# How to click into multiple elements that is not in the view yet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have updated question.
here is my code. after opening url it will only click one or two elements. if you zoom out the page all elements will be visible and all element will be clicked.

```
import time 
# importing webdriver from selenium 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
# Here Chrome  will be used 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
#ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.sl.find_element_by_id('my-id')).perform()
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://eksisozluk.com/stack-overflow--136193")
time.sleep(2)

buttons=driver.find_elements_by_id("svg-chevron-down")
for i in buttons:
    try:
        i.click()
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(1)
```

[trying to click pointing down elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4JrL.png)

### original post

in a webpage i have list of elements but some of them is not in the view(at the downside of page). I can not scroll down randomly because i can not know whether or not that element can be seen by mouse at that position. I need a code that automatically scroll into that element.

`actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()`  does not work because it does not move if element is not in the view.

```
       like_buttons= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("like")
       for element in like_buttons:
           #here put some code that moves to that element
           i.click()
```

I found this code

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",i)
```

but it does not work since I have multiple elements.( like_buttons has 100 elements)
also

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((i))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((i))).click()
```

these two does not work to.

to sum up, I want my code to automatically scroll into elements and click. But multiple elements make it complicated. what should I do. I use python, selenium. I do not know much javascript. If you simply tell me what should I write in the for loop I would be appreciated.

Comment: to visualize , think twitter . in  your timeline you want to automatically like all tweets.(I will not use it on twitter)

Comment: i want to ask another thing to, after like elements class turn into "like done" . but like_buttons= driver.find_elements_by_class_name("like") also involves "like done" class. I use like_buttons list repeatedly but clicking double takes back the like

Comment: you could create minimal working code with real url so we could simply copy and run it - to see problem and test some ideas.

Comment: i have updated post and add my code. if you try code you can see. thanks

Comment: `except: pass` is big mistake - you get error but you can't see it - so you can't search what is the real problem. You could remove it when you develop program and later you could use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` to still have some information when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried you minimal working code with

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", i)
```

and it was moving elements ... but it was moving every element to window's top border and element was hidden behind `header` with navigation menu - so it was not visible and not clickable.

So I tried to scroll element little down to make it visible

```
driver.execute_script("scrollBy(0, -150)")
```

but it made problem with last element which was moved below window's bottom border and it was not visible and not clickable.

Finally I released I can remove `header` and all items moved to window's top border will be visible and clickable.

```
header = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/header")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].remove();", header)
```

And this way it can click all items.

---

I had to use `[:-1]` to skip last item which was not displayed.

---

Minimal working code

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://eksisozluk.com/stack-overflow--136193")
time.sleep(1)

# find header and remove it
header = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/header")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].remove();", header)

buttons = driver.find_elements_by_id("svg-chevron-down")[:-1] # skip last hidden element
print('len:', len(buttons))

for i in buttons:
    print('i:', i)

    try:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", i)
        time.sleep(0.2)  # to make sure it moved 
        i.click()
    except Exception as ex:
        print('EX:', ex)

    time.sleep(0.5)
```

---

**BTW:** instead of removing `header` you may try to hide it with CSS `display:none`. So later you could show it back - if you will need it.

---

**EDIT:**

I created version which moves element to window's top border (`scrollIntoView`), next it get element's position and if it behind header then it move it down (`scrollBy`) but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. It looks like sometimes `scrollBy` has problem to move or it  moves and `getBoundingClientRect` shows new position but `click` can't find object. Maybe with `WebDriverWait` it would work better.

I put code because it can be useful as idea for something better.

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://eksisozluk.com/stack-overflow--136193")
time.sleep(2)

# get header height
header = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/header")
rect = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect();", header)
header_height = rect['height']
print('header height:', header_height)

# calculate offset for `scrollBy`
#offset = 150
offset = int(header_height + 20)  # (height + some_margin_to_make_sure)
print('offset:', offset)

buttons = driver.find_elements_by_id("svg-chevron-down")[:-1] # skip last hidden element
print('len:', len(buttons))

for number, i in enumerate(buttons, 1):
    print('\n---', number, '---\n')

    try:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", i)
        time.sleep(0.2)  # to make sure it moved 

        rect = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect();", i)
        time.sleep(0.2)  # to make sure it moved 
        print('rect.top:', rect['top'])

        # check if behind `header`
        if rect['top'] < offset:             # if rect['top'] < 150
            cmd = f'window.scrollBy(0, -{offset});'
            print(cmd)                       #     print('scrollBy(0, -150)')
            driver.execute_script(cmd)       #     driver.execute_script("scrollBy(0, -150)")
            time.sleep(0.1)  # to make sure it moved 

            rect = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect();", i)
            print('rect.top:', rect['top'])
  
        i.click()
    except Exception as ex:
        print('EX:', ex)

    time.sleep(0.5)
```